# How to set PDF version using iTextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I need to set pdf version from 1.5 to 1.4 but I am unable to do it with the help of iTextSharp.
Here is my code

```
  char ch = '4';

        string pdfFile = @"C:\Users\p.kulkarni\Desktop\PDF_Files\OCR.pdf";
        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFile))
        {

            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(@"D:\KK_T.pdf", FileMode.Create),'4'))
            {
                stamper.FormFlattening = true;
                stamper.Writer.PdfVersion = '4';
                stamper.Writer.SetAtLeastPdfVersion('4');
                stamper.Writer.SetFullCompression();
                stamper.Writer.CompressionLevel = PdfStream.BEST_COMPRESSION;

                //stamper.CompressionLevel = PdfStream.BEST_COMPRESSION;
                stamper.SetFullCompression();

            }
        }
```

But still I am get any success.
Can you help me to set PDF version ? PDF version is not change with above code

Here is my attached PDF...[DEMO PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B79L1PJQrt26aXdrT2trYU5MVlE/edit?usp=sharing)
Thanks in advance
koolprasad2003

Comment: Well... `SetFullCompression` means that you want to use object streams and a compressed cross-reference table. That wasn't supported in PDF 1.4. Only software compliant with PDF 1.5 can read such files, so you're actually trying to do something that will break your PDFs with respect to the 1.4 PDF reference.

Comment: I have tried by removing 'SetFullCompression' but it still convert it to 1.5 version but I want 1.4 what other steps should I follow to accomplish my task

Comment: Did you remove it on every level? `stamper.Writer.SetFullCompression();` as well as `stamper.SetFullCompression();`?

Comment: Basically I need to set version 1.4 to my pdf but I am not able to do it, Do you have any code sample ? so that I can accomplish my task

Comment: Your sample should work (assuming that you remove all the full compression stuff). If it doesn't: show us the PDF.

Comment: I have tried with the same but no luck, you can find attached pdf in my question post. Please help to resolve the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at the [ChangeVersion](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/stamper/ChangeVersion) example I made:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest), '4');
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

In this example, I create a `PdfReader` and a `PdfStamper`. In the `PdfStamper`, I tell iText that I want the version of the file to change to version 4.

Once I close the stamper, the magic is done. Please check the file [other_version.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/other_version.pdf) to convince yourself that this works.

One observation: your original file [OCR.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/OCR.pdf) has a compressed cross-reference table. If you would open this file in a text editor, and manually change the version number from 1.6 to 1.4, Adobe Reader will tell you that the file is an 1.5 file because compressed cross-reference tables didn't exist in PDF 1.4. They were introduced in PDF 1.5.

In this case, iText will uncompress the cross-reference table, resulting in a valid 1.4 PDF file. However: iText doesn't downgrade *all* new functionality automatically. If a specific PDF contains newer functionality (e.g. OCGs), then iText won't remove those OCGs if you change the PDF version to a version predating the introduction of OCG.

Comment: Thanks for your help Bruno Lowagie, now can I able to create file with version 1.4, but how how can I set its fastwebview property to true, how can I set make PDF linearized using iTextSharp

Comment: iTextSharp doesn't support Linearization (aka FastWebView).